# how do I scale points so their average distance is sqrt(2)?

Tags: linear-transformations

According to [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision, Second Edition](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf), pg 109, I need to

> Compute a similarity transformation T that takes points xi to a new
>   set of points x˜i such that their average distance from the origin is
>   √2.

Finding the average distance is easy.  In python it is

```
np.mean(np.hypot(pts))
```

And a similarity transform is, I guess, just multiplying every point by some scale value - but what is that value to end up with a certain average distance?  And how do I calculate it?

Comment: Scale by root 2 over mean distance

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: It’s hard to say what might be going wrong, but multiplying all your old coordinates by $\sqrt {2}$ and dividing out the old mean distance should do it.

Comment: Are you recomputing the mean distance each time? If so then you would be using the wrong coordinates for the later points, you should only do one mean distance computation

Comment: are there 2 scale factors?  one for x and one for y?  I was just doing one value.

Comment: No, only one factor, just multiply everything by  sqrt(2)/(old mean distance)

Comment: Fixed.  I was multiplying only one axis by the scale   Thank you very much.

Comment: make an answer and I can mark it as the solution and you earn points